# Where to stand for this winter view in Grindelwald, Switzerland?

Tags: switzerland, identify-this

I happened upon [this r/winterporn post](https://redd.it/85367l). If you haven't stood at this spot, how did you infer where it was?

[image]

Comment: The lighting designer in me is cringing at the mismatch between LPS (the orange), HPS (yellow), metal halide, mercury vapor and various colors of LED lighting.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I'm not sure how many of those are fixed and how many are vehicle lights, but the contrast between sodium street lights, halogen car headlights, and LED bike headlights was, for a few years, very useful when cycling.  Now everything is going to white LEDs I have less warning of approaching vehicles at some points. It's all about your use case! Yours of course could be fixed in post (or [ruined](https://imgur.com/a/lMyTwnz) by bad shopping)

Comment: @ChrisH That's easy. The train headlight is very bright, and it can be seen actually following the curvature of the track. *They don't normally do that*.  That makes it a time lapse. Vehicles will leave streaks not spots.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I was certain there were some fixed and some moving but it seems to have been downscaled from an image with blown highlights I couldn't say that all the linear lights are vehicles as opposed to rows of lights or reflections from snowbanks

Comment: Any time you have not been in Grindelwald for, say, two months - you miss Grindelwald.  :/

Comment: Winterporn! I love it!

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica it looks christmasy though. Btw OP, this is long exposure. Don't expect it to be this bright irl.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I've been in Grindelwald early September this year (when there was no snow) but the hill in the background (top two thirds of the picture) is still recognizable as the hill south of the village which leads to Kleine Scheidegg.

After a bit of matching with the 3D view of Google Maps ([approximate link](https://www.google.com/maps/@46.632466,8.0336461,903a,35y,209.54h,61.95t/data=!3m1!1e3)) I've identified the Stutzgasse (right red circle) and the railroad (left red circle) which leads up to Kleine Scheidegg:

[image]

[image]

The next question would be which street on the north hill (the main village) corresponds to the houses in the foreground. I failed to find them at first but it seems to be the [Nirggen](https://www.google.com/maps/@46.6225204,8.0263504,3a,75y,183.8h,99.09t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sDhpBfe0k_QptfvxirRKYYg!2e0!7i13312!8i6656); the house in the blue circle is quite recognizable:

[image]

The photo must have been shot from a slightly higher point, somewhere around [here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/46%C2%B037'28.2%22N+8%C2%B001'40.5%22E/@46.624504,8.0267888,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x0:0x0!7e2!8m2!3d46.6245036!4d8.027923). There's no Google Street View from that road, but [this](https://www.google.com/maps/@46.6252663,8.027397,3a,75y,233.52h,67.71t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sG-SgFiZMcXFareqmX9zr4g!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) slightly higher road comes close (I've highlighted the railroad and the gray house again):

[image]

Views further to the east are blocked by the houses on the Dorfstrasse, and [this place](https://www.google.com/maps/@46.6243261,8.0297536,3a,75y,225.27h,75.54t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1sAF1QipPhr9Ahecscg4AJDPCEq_RzmV7cax811rH81XDM!2e10!3e11!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipPhr9Ahecscg4AJDPCEq_RzmV7cax811rH81XDM%3Dw203-h100-k-no-pi-0-ya282.0559-ro0-fo100!7i11264!8i5632) (photo shot in the summer) is already too far to the east.

Comment: Your find also proves this shot is a time exposure.  The headlight of the train can be seen curving along the route.

Answer (score 11):

The original image might possibly be from this blog.

http://qalam-graphics.blog.ir/1396/10/01/Publication69

A similar image is this one

[image: hotel image]

And the hotel is

[Hotel Cabana Grindelwald](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g188080-d291733-Reviews-Hotel_Cabana-Grindelwald_Jungfrau_Region_Bernese_Oberland_Canton_of_Bern.html)

[image: Hotel Cabana-Grindelwald Jungfrau Region Bernese Oberland Canton of Bern]

[This photo of Hotel Cabana](https://www.tripadvisor.com/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g188080-d291733-i45281080-Hotel_Cabana-Grindelwald_Jungfrau_Region_Bernese_Oberland_Canton_of_Bern.html#45281080) is courtesy of TripAdvisor

Comment: My method of finding this was less sexy than Glorfindel's. I used image search on Google, Bing and Tineye.

Comment: Yep, that's definitely the same dark brown house (barn?) as the closest one in the picture in the question. Well done, I'm glad we've solved this mystery :)

Comment: Guys, what's with all the google .. tech .. stuff.  The Schoenegg most famously has the best views like that and it's probably taken from like the room upstairs on the left.  (Looking to the left from there.)  Surely there is someone on here who lives in or near Grindelwald!!

Comment: @Fattie , google is more accurate than a guess. The Parkhotel Schoenegg does not look out on the yard and cabin next to the Hotel Cabana. It is more likely the Jungfrau Lodge or one of the places nearby.

Answer (score 2):

Its hotel cabana for sure[image]
[image]
Here is my version

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's taken from a verandah at one of the rooms at the left end of the Schoenegg ... Parkhotel Schoenegg.

(That is to say, ask for one of the rooms with the Eiger-side view.) (But look to your left.)

Say hi to Tschingel!